# How to add custom headers to an open id connect authentication request in OWIN middleware

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, oauth, openid, identityserver3

I have a system where I have an MVC website calling a web api. I have used OAUTH and OPENID Connect for my authentication/authorization. I have setup an identity server in another web api project using Thinktecture's IdentityServer3. In the MVC project I am doing the redirect to the identity server in the OWIN Startup class. This is all pretty standard stuff and is working fine.

I have now been asked to put the web api and the identity server behind Azure API Management. This also, is fine as all I need to do from my MVC project is add my subscription key from API management as a header ("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key") to any request to the web api. So far so good.

The problem is I now need to add this header to any requests to the identity server and I can't work out how, other than writing my own middleware. My Startup class looks like this:

```
public class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new SimpleInjectorDependencyResolver(IocHelper.GetContainer()));

        JwtSecurityTokenHandler.InboundClaimTypeMap = new Dictionary<string, string>();

        app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = "Cookies"
        });

        app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
        {
            ClientId = ConfigurationHelper.GetClientId(),
            Authority = ConfigurationHelper.GetSecurityTokenServiceUrl(),
            RedirectUri = ConfigurationHelper.GetPortalHomePageUrl(),
            PostLogoutRedirectUri = ConfigurationHelper.GetPortalHomePageUrl(),
            ResponseType = "code id_token",
            Scope = "openid profile public_api",
            TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                NameClaimType = "name",
                RoleClaimType = "role"
            },

            SignInAsAuthenticationType = "Cookies",


            Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
            {
                AuthorizationCodeReceived = async n =>
                {
                    // use the code to get the access and refresh token
                    var tokenClient = new TokenClient(ConfigurationHelper.GetTokenEndpointUrl(), ConfigurationHelper.GetClientId(), ConfigurationHelper.GetClientSecret());
                    var tokenResponse = await tokenClient.RequestAuthorizationCodeAsync(n.Code, n.RedirectUri);
                    if (tokenResponse.IsError)
                    {
                        throw new Exception(tokenResponse.Error);
                    }

                    // use the access token to retrieve claims from userinfo
                    var userInfoClient = new UserInfoClient(ConfigurationHelper.GetUserInfoUrl());
                    var userInfoResponse = await userInfoClient.GetAsync(tokenResponse.AccessToken);
                    if (userInfoResponse.IsError)
                    {
                        throw new Exception(userInfoResponse.Error);
                    }

                    // create new identity
                    var id = new ClaimsIdentity(n.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.AuthenticationType);
                    foreach (var c in userInfoResponse.Claims)
                    {
                        id.AddClaim(new Claim(c.Type, c.Value));
                    }

                    id.AddClaim(new Claim("access_token", tokenResponse.AccessToken));
                    id.AddClaim(new Claim("expires_at", DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(tokenResponse.ExpiresIn * 2).ToLocalTime().ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)));
                    id.AddClaim(new Claim("id_token", n.ProtocolMessage.IdToken));
                    id.AddClaim(new Claim("sid", n.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.FindFirst("sid").Value));


                    var claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(id.Claims, n.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.AuthenticationType, "name", "role");
                    //claimsIdentity.IsAuthenticated = true;
                    n.AuthenticationTicket = new AuthenticationTicket(claimsIdentity, n.AuthenticationTicket.Properties);
                },
                RedirectToIdentityProvider = n =>
                {
                    // if signing out, add the id_token_hint
                    if (n.ProtocolMessage.RequestType != OpenIdConnectRequestType.LogoutRequest)
                    {
                        return Task.FromResult(0);
                    }

                    var idTokenHint = n.OwinContext.Authentication.User.FindFirst("id_token");

                    if (idTokenHint != null)
                    {
                        n.ProtocolMessage.IdTokenHint = idTokenHint.Value;
                    }

                    // DOESN'T WORK
                    n.OwinContext.Request.Headers.Append("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", "MY KEY GOES HERE");

                    // ALSO DOESN'T WORK
                    n.Request.Headers.Append("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", "MY KEY GOES HERE");

                    return Task.FromResult(0);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Is there a way to hi-jack the request to the identity server and add my own header in there?

Comment: There is a notification that gets called before the request gets sent called `RedirectToIdentityProvider` you might be able to find something in there to help you. From my last look at the source of the middleware, the `ProtocolMessage` is possibly where you might want to override something

Comment: I deleted my answer as it did not work, but this was OP's last comment on there that explained his work around 
`Thanks again. In the end, I set the Identity server endpoint behind to API Management to not require a subscription which means I don't need to add a header. Doesn't answer the question but works around the problem. Not pretty but it works.`